# Cannot add elements to a CollectionView on Xamarin Forms iOS without hiding/deforming existing items

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Here is a sample app that illustrates my problem (full source at: https://github.com/cmpalmer66/CollectionViewSample)

It works fine on UWP and Android, but on iOS, if you click the Add Label or Add Entry buttons, the preloaded list of 20 items disappears (or shrinks to 0 height). Adding more controls still just displays the last one, moving down the page. Occasionally, one of the previously added controls will show up at random.

Basically just wondering if I'm doing something wrong or if this is a bug.

MainPage.xaml

```
<StackLayout>
    <Button Text="Add Label" Clicked="Button1_OnClicked" />
    <Button Text="Add Entry" Clicked="Button2_OnClicked" />

    <CollectionView x:Name="MyCollectionView">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentView Content="{Binding .}"></ContentView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CollectionViewSample
{
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyCollectionView.BindingContext = this;
            MyCollectionView.SetBinding(ItemsView.ItemsSourceProperty, nameof(ControlList));
            // Adding these 20 items all at once works fine
            for (var x = 0; x < 20; x++)
            {
                ControlList.Add(new Label {Text = $"Added at {ControlList.Count}"});
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<View> ControlList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<View>();

        private void Button1_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Adding a single control to the ControlList will mess up the display of the previously
            // added items on iOS
            ControlList.Add(new Label {Text = $"Added at {ControlList.Count}"});
        }

        private void Button2_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Adding a single control to the ControlList will mess up the display of the previously
            // added items on iOS
            ControlList.Add(new Entry {Text = $"Added at {ControlList.Count}"});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you use [DataTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector) instead of setting the ItemSource to View and [Choose item appearance at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data#choose-item-appearance-at-runtime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a simple sample:

Create a **ViewTemplateSelector** :

```
public class ViewTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate LebelTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate EntryTemplate { get; set; }
    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        return ((CollectionData)item).Type == 1 ? LebelTemplate : EntryTemplate;
    }
}
```

then use in your page xaml:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="labelTemplate">
        
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
  
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="entryTemplate">

                <Entry Text="{Binding Name}"/>

        </DataTemplate>
        <local:ViewTemplateSelector x:Key="viewTemplateSelector"
            LebelTemplate="{StaticResource labelTemplate}"
            EntryTemplate="{StaticResource entryTemplate}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Button Text="Add Label" Clicked="Button1_Clicked" />
        <Button Text="Add Entry" Clicked="Button2_Clicked" />

        <CollectionView x:Name="MyCollectionView"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource viewTemplateSelector}" >

        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

create a data mode ,add a `Type` to determine which template to use (here 1 means add Label,2 means add Entry)：

```
public class CollectionData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
}
```

in your page.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyCollectionView.BindingContext = this;
        MyCollectionView.SetBinding(ItemsView.ItemsSourceProperty, nameof(ControlList));
        // Adding these 20 items all at once works fine
        for (var x = 0; x < 20; x++)
        {
             ControlList.Add(new CollectionData { Name = $"Added at {ControlList.Count}",Type = 1 });
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<CollectionData> ControlList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<CollectionData>();

    private void Button1_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Adding a single control to the ControlList will mess up the display of the previously
        // added items on iOS
         ControlList.Add(new CollectionData { Name = $"Added at {ControlList.Count}",Type = 1 });
    }

    private void Button2_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Adding a single control to the ControlList will mess up the display of the previously
        // added items on iOS
         ControlList.Add(new CollectionData { Name = $"Added at {ControlList.Count}",Type = 2 });
    }
}
```

Comment: This may work for the sample, but my actual application for this is much more complicated, where each control rendered from the ObservableCollection<View> is a composite control composed inside a grid and containing its own bindings and a custom control.

Comment: Are you saying this is the only workaround? The technique works well enough in StackLayout and TableView, but they each have their own problems with what we're trying to do. The StackLayout wants to manage which element(s) have focus and visibility and the TableView has problems with the heights (which probably need separate issues). This technique works fine on UWP and Android, but iOS appears to be broken.

Comment: Informative answer, but not quite a solution I'm looking for.

Comment: You could define your composite control in the datatemplate,not only like one Entry or Label above.